# Predict how many times the ball will land on red or black

Tags: probability

A roulette wheel has 38 slots around the rim. The first 36 slots are numbers from 1 to 36. Half of the 36 slots are red, the other half are black. The remaining 2 slots are numbered 0 and 00 and are green. If the roulette wheel is spun 114 times, predict about how many times the ball will land on red or black?

Comment: First step: If the wheel is spun once, what is the probability that the ball lands on, say black?

Comment: Have you calculated the probability that the ball will land on red or black when the wheel is spun once?  Where are you stuck?  You should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Hint: $114=3\cdot 38$. This was chosen to make your answer easier. Every thirty-eight spins, you expect how many red and black results

Answer (score 1):

Under ideal conditions, every $38$ spins the ball will land on red $18$ times, black $18$ and green $2$ times.

So after $114$ spins, we expect there to be $54$ reds and $54$ blacks, with $6$ greens.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable denoting the event that the spinner landed on red or black on the $i^{th}$ trial.

I.e. for each $i\in\{1,2,\dots,118\}$ let $X_i=\begin{cases}1~\text{if the roulette landed on red or black on the}~i^{th}~\text{trial}\\
0~\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then, letting $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{118}X_i$, you have $X=$ total number of times the spinner landed on red or black out of 118 trials.

We have $E[X]=E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{118}X_i]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{118}E[X_i]$ by the linearity of expectation.

We see that $E[X_i]=E[X_j]$ for every $i,j\in\{1,2,\dots,118\}$, so the above simplifies to simply $118E[X_i]$.

In a single trial, the probability that the spinner lands on red or black is $\frac{36}{38}$.

We have then as a final answer $E[X]=118\cdot \frac{36}{38}= 108$

Comment: What is $X_j$ in this context?

Comment: @N.F. an indicator variable for if the $j^{th}$ trial landed on a red or black.  My point being, each trial has the same probability and the same expectation.  For explicit example, $E[X_1]=E[X_7]$

Comment: Your edit made that clear.

Comment: But will it be clear to the OP ? :)

Answer (score 0):

@brandi Deriving solution to this problem involves two simple steps.

1. First find the probability of ball landing on red or black in one trial. it is 
   1 - {probability of ball landing on green} => 1 - $\frac {2}{36}$ => $\frac {34}{36}$
2. Now calculate for 114 trials. it is 
   114 * $\frac {34}{36}$ => 108